# Looping Through Multiple Shapefiles - GDAL/OGR - Possible Performance Issues

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, performance

I am trying to filter data from *shapefile1* based on specific attributes in *shapefile2*. Specifically, I would like to determine if numbered ranges within *shapefile1* have been reversed in *shapefile2*, given that both records share the same parcel identifier.

My initial solution is to iterate over the two tables like so...

```
def get_reversed(shp_1, shp_2):
    shapefile1 = shp_1
    shapefile2 = shp_2
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    dataSource1 = driver.Open(Shapefile1, 0)
    dataSource2 = driver.Open(Shapefile2, 0)
    layer1 = dataSource1.GetLayer()
    layer2 = dataSource2.GetLayer()

    for feature2 in layer2:
        range2 = '-'.join(feature2.GetField("RANGE").split('-')[::-1])
        pid2 = feature.GetField("PARCEL_ID")
        layer1.SetAttributeFilter("RANGE = '{}' AND PARCEL_ID = '{}'".format(range2, pid2))

        for feature1 in layer1:
            print('2000 range: {}: Parcel ID: {}'.format(feature1.GetField("RANGE"), feature1.GetField("PARCEL_ID")))
            print('2010 range: {}: Parcel ID: {}'.format(feature2.GetField("RANGE"), feature2.GetField("PARCEL_ID")))
            print('----------------------------')
```

I have no reason to believe that this technique doesn't work, but the program just seems to run forever. In this case, the parcel tables have over 40,000 columns each, and my 0(n^2) algorithm appears too slow to handle the size.

Am I right to think that this code is "too slow" for the data size, or am I completely off path? Can someone show me a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Would loading one of the layer's attributes in to a dictionary and then reading over that for each feature in the other layer be a faster alternative?

Comment: Try spatialite, make join between 2 layers and do the query.

Comment: i would create new column for reversed range first, after that loop f1 for every parcel_id, there could be some  join call in python do it in one call and/or there might some index related stuff which speeds things up

Answer (score 2):

Just following up on this question as I did end up finding a solution. I loaded the first layer into a python dictionary, which greatly increased the program speed.

Here is the what the revised version looks like.

```
def get_reversed(shp1, shp2):
    shapefile1 = shp1
    shapefile2 = shp2
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    dataSource1 = driver.Open(Shapefile1, 0)
    dataSource2 = driver.Open(shapefile2, 0)
    layer1 = dataSource1.GetLayer()
    layer2 = dataSource2.GetLayer()

    # load layer1 target attributes into dict.
    dict = {}
    for feature in layer1:
        parcel_id = feature.GetField("PARCEL_ID")
        if parcel_id in dict.keys():
            dict[parcel_id].append(feature.GetField("RANGE"))
        else:
            dict[parcel_id] = [feature.GetField("RANGE")]

    # compare layer2 with values in dict
    for feature in layer2:
        reversed_range = '-'.join(feature.GetField("Range").split('-')[::-1])
        parcel_id = feature.GetField("PARCEL_ID")
        keys = dict.keys()

        if parcel_id in keys:
            for range in dict[parcel_id]:
                if range == reversed_range:
                    print('Reverse found: {}'.format(parcel_id))
                else: pass
            else: pass
```

"PARCEL_ID" is not a unique identifier in this case, which is why lists are loaded into the dictionary instead of single "PARCEL_ID" values.